# Log someone out if the same credentials is used to log in from another web client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, authentication

In a ASP.NET MVC application, is it possible to log someone out, if the login credentials is used on another web client?

For e.g.,

1) user login from PC A, with user id admin
2) another user logs in with user id admin from PC B
3) PC A gets signed out

Comment: you could check on each login if current user already online like so -
 MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(username);
if(user.IsOnline) { do something }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at setting a token on the client cookie. This token can be checked for subsequent calls and if it doesn't match then kick the user off.

So, in terms of a use case...

1. Create a table - LoggedInUsers that has, say, the UserID, Token
2. When user logs in on browser A you can check against the LoggedInUsers table to see if they are currently logged in and have a matching token. If they don't exist, then create a token and store it in their cookie and add the entry to the table. If they are in the table and do have a matching token then they are the same browser. If they are in the DB but the token doesn't match then you choose whether you want the new user to have their token overwrite the existing one or prevent logging in.

now ever page call should check the LoggedInUsers table so you can log the user out if they are logged in via another browser.

Hope that makes sense...